# async function for advice generator

Tags: javascript, async-await

All code is working well but whenever I click the button to generate an advice, the advice is delayed and it's not showing in my site whenever the circle is clicked.

Is there a way for me to sync perfectly the button and the generated advice ?

How can I improve my code?

```js
const number = document.querySelector(".number");
const advice = document.querySelector(".advice");
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle")

async function randomAdvice() {
  try {
    const random = await fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice");
    console.log(random)
    const adviceGenerated = await random.json();
    console.log(adviceGenerated)
    number.textContent = `#${adviceGenerated.slip.id}`;
    advice.textContent = `"${adviceGenerated.slip.advice}"`;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
randomAdvice();

circle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  randomAdvice()
});
```

```html
<button class="circle">Circle</button>
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="advice"></div>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is it showing delayed, or is it not showing at all?

Comment: Your `fetch` and `random.json()`,  will obviously take time, how can the system show you the return before you have got the return?.   Or do you mean you want to get the random advice, and then only show when you click?

Comment: The delay isn't significant to me.

Comment: @Keith I think I've parsed it now -- he means the top-level `randomAdvice()` is working but delayed, and the ones triggered by the click aren't working at all. But I can't reproduce that in the snippet.

Comment: When I click the `circle` in the live site the response is showing right away in the console but not in the live view of the site which supposed to generate new advice in the textContent of both `number` and `advice`

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console? Do you see the requests and responses in the Network tab?

Comment: @pichimnc I added simple HTML when I created the snippet, and it works fine. There must be something else in your site that's interfering with the `textContent` display. You need to post a [mre].

Comment: Seen as this is a Rest request using fetch, browsers have a limit on the number of requests sent by each Tab, I believe it's 5 concurrent requests.  If you look in your browsers network tab, do you have lots of active requests open?.  Another problem might be do the API have request limits etc..

Comment: A quick google for Chrome ->  `Chrome has a limit of 6 connections per host name, and a max of 10 connections. `   So could your live site be hitting these causing slowdowns..

Comment: No, there's no error in my console whenever I click the button. Yes, I think @Keith you're right it's the concurrent request. Is there a way for me fix it?

Comment: @pichimnc  It's going to depend what the other requests do, are they all needed?.  If so could you stagger the other requests, run them in series etc.  Unfortunately without knowing the details of your live website it's a little tricky to give advice on how to fix.  If all these concurrent connections are required, one idea is create some sort of proxy server, and connect to this via web sockets, but that's not going to be a trivial task.. :(

Comment: I understand that now! I think I I got what you guys are explaining! Thank you for all help !